# Canvas won't display

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, canvas, charts

Working with Chart js and have run into a bit of trouble. I am trying to pull some data from a web service (which I am doing just fine) but when I try to place it into the chart, the chart doesn't display. I am pulling the data from [here](https://api.myjson.com/bins/59zvx) just fine. The console prints out the expected values, even the interval works to make sure nothing has changed.

Also the `canvas` div shows up on the page, just the chart doesn't animate. The html here is pretty straight forward, as I am just using it for a small widget:

```
  <body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="canvas-holder">
      <canvas id="chart-area" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="randomizeData">Randomize Data</button>
  </body>
```

And [here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1xIbSmXmNvPL3F4W8qvx?p=preview) so you can better understand whats going on. If you view the console you can see there are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut($scope.doughnutData, {
    responsive: true
});
```

inside sucess callback. That will solved.

```
.success(function(returnedData) {    
     $scope.doughnutData = sortByKey($scope.doughnutData, 'value');

     // Put code here

});
```

Comment: Would you maybe update the plunker? I tried to edit it and it shows up for a split second the disappears. The plunker I linked has the updated code in it so you can follow the same link to check it out?